# Site is redirecting from checkout page to cart page

Tags: checkout, cart

I am working with a site http://www.themaorishop.co.nz ... In this, on some system after selecting shipping method page is redirected to cart page and operation is not completing. I am not able to find problem. Please have a look.

Comment: Check your php server log file and your javascript error console

Comment: Most probably the problem is in the antivirus program especially if it is Kaspersky Internet Security. Please disable/pause it and try again.

Comment: Thanks @michael, It was the same issue you have described.

Comment: hi @michael, is there any solution to sort out this problem?

Comment: No, @Andrew, sorry. You can try to post a message in Kaspersky forum http://forum.kaspersky.com/ . Maybe the URL is blacklisted. I know about this problem because I am using Kaspersky too but never find a real solution.

Answer (score 3):

I can't say without more information, but I can bet your problem lies somewhere between `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`'s `saveShippingMethodAction` and `_expireAjax` methods.

I know this because on the shipping method step, when the data is POST'd, no re-direct URL is set in the case of an error (in fact the `saveShippingMethodAction` does not even catch and handle errors like other steps do).

Therefore, I'd start observing the `_expireAjax` call at the top of that method. It's **here** that you can get a redirect response, under any of the following conditions:

- If the quote (cart) has no items
- If the quote has an error
- If multi-shipping is enabled
- If the cart was altered after the first step

Also try debugging from the client-side, by setting breakpoints in `opcheckout.js` in the `Checkout` class, `ajaxFailure` method. If the debugger stops in that method, see your call stack for any clues about the response received from the server.

**Ref: `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`**

**Ref: `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js`**

Comment: As michael described about kaspersky antivirus, when i disabled that the execution is going through, so is there any solution to sort out that problem because we can not tell customer to turn off their antivirus while using our service.

Comment: If it seems Kaspersky related, best to follow the trail of @michael. Even so, when this occurs, you should verify the response headers that take you back to the cart. If you get a `403 Session Expired` header, then my answer is telling of that. In which case, could this anti-virus software be tampering with your sessions?

Answer (score 2):

I experience this same thing in my magento site. I got an perfect solution which resolved the problem is PHP version. I have changed PHP version 5.4 to 5.5 from the cPanel and it works fine.

Follow the Steps :

1. Login into cPanel
2. Move to > Software and Services
3. Click on > Select PHP Version
4. Check your Current PHP version: 5.X (In my case it was 5.4)
5. Select PHP Version 5.5 in Dropdown
6. At last click on > Set as current

Hope it is works for you.